How to test extension functions in Swift?
I'm currently working on unit testing for my presenter class, which implements a class with its methods. The issue I'm facing is that this class has methods declared in an extension, and when I'm creating the mock objects, I cannot override these functions. I'm feeling a bit lost about how to solve this or improve my code. I can provide a code sample to make it easier to understand:
class Presenter {
    func actionCall() {
        analytics.sendClick(.call)
        router.callPhone(phoneKey.localized)
    }
}
extension Analytics {

    func sendClick(_ tag: Enum.Click) {
       sendClick(tag.rawValue)
}
class Analytics {
    func sendClick(_ code: String) {
       send(hitType: .click, eventType: .navigation, code: code)
}

